# Unable to find Central Administration

Tags: 2013, central-administration, iis

I just attempted to install Workflow Manager and since then I have not been able to access CA. All it shows is that the Page Cannot be Found. Both of these are running on the same server and both are communicating via https. In IIS it says that everything is started. I've also tried restarting them as well.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Try running the config wizard again and have it continue to host the CA.It should resolve the problem.

Also, look for the error log to find the relevant information.

Comment: did you tried any of the above suggestions.

Comment: yes, and they were a great help, I solved it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: explain the actual solution and mark the comments or answers with votes so it would help others.

Answer (score 0):

open up IIS Manager

1. Start > Type INETMGR in the search textbox and run it.
2. When IIS Manager opens click the server name in the "Connections" panel.
3. Expand the "Sites" node.
4. Select "Central Administration" and click "Browse Web Site" in the "Actions" panel.

Note the URL and you should be able to access "Central Administration"

Comment: Can you please mark answer as useful if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Please check "SharePoint Administration Service" if it's started. Sometimes it could be stopped by some installations in SharePoint like as Workflow Manager.